# Wordpress Lightbox plus plugin and google chrome scrollbar

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm using wordpress lightbox plus plugin: http://www.23systems.net/plugins/lightbox-plus/

And it's working well but the problem is when viewed on google chrome, scrollbars appear on the lightbox overlay image.

Here's the link:
http://goo.gl/2Yy9L

Note: click on the 3 mini images at the bottom [ this is where lighbox plus is applied]

Answer (score 0):

On the div with id `cboxLoadedContent` you have overflow-x and overflow-y set to auto. The content doesn't quite fit. You can either make the content fit in its container thus avoiding the scrollbars or you can apply `overflow: hidden` which will dispose of scrollbars entirely. Of course some of the image could be hidden. It looks good though so I imagine it is just a pixel hor/vert and won't be missed.

Comment: where do I change it to hidden?

Comment: depends where the styles are declared. I'd start by checking whatever css files come with lightbox. You could also just try declaring it in your WP stylesheet and hope it works.  `#cboxLoadedContent { overflow: hidden; }`